# Appended but style not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
var dom = '<div data-id="'+id+'" class="box box_album_item"><div class="album_item"  style="background: url('+img_src+') no-repeat center center; background-size: cover; height="'+ $('#album_item .album_item:first').outerWidth() +'px"></div></div>';

$('#abc').append(dom);
```

everything worked, I'm able to see the height in my dom,

[image]

but the height is not applied?

Comment: Typo: `height="'+ ` should be just `height: ' + `

Comment: As a pure suggestion of style, I'd rewrite the first line in 2 or 3 lines so that it's not readable. Compilers will treat it just the same but to read it'll be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have mention "height=", you are giving a style not attribute use "height:" instead.
    var dom = '
                 
     
';

```
$('#abc').append(dom);
```

Answer (score 0):

change from **height="** to **height:**

```
var dom = '<div data-id="'+id+'" class="box box_album_item"><div class="album_item"  style="background: url('+img_src+') no-repeat center center;  background-size: cover; height:'+ $('#album_item .album_item:first').outerWidth() +'px"></div></div>';
```

Comment: That's not the problem

Comment: @frenchie why not? it's closing the style attribute of the div, so the height it's outside the div's style property.

Comment: Because it's css: height='+ $('#album_item .album_item:first').outerWidth() +'px" should be height: css doesn't use equal sign.

Comment: ups, you're right. but anyway it's wrong his code, now i correct my anwer